# Python finding local maxima/minima for multiple polynomials efficiently

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, polynomials

I am looking for an efficient way to find local mins for multiple (>1 million) but independent 4th order polynomials in **given/ specified ranges/ boundaries**.

I have two requirements:

**R1: efficient even for 1 million different polynomial equations**

**R2: the local min is accurate up to 0.01 (i.e. 2dp)**

Here is some code I have created using `scipy`. It's okay but I am wondering **if there's any other better packages in performing such a task** before I go for parallel programming.

To illustrate my problem, let's start with one polynomial first:

Below I am trying to find the local min of 4x^4 + 6x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 5 within the range (-5, 5).

On my laptop, it takes about 2ms to find the local min (which is at ~ -0.72770502).

The time is alright for one polynomial but I would want something faster as I need to perform this operation over 1 million times regularly.

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

# Define a objective and gradient function for 4th order polynomial
# x is the value to be evaluated
# par is a numpy array of len 5 that specifies the polynomial coefficients.
def obj_grad_fun_custom(x,par):
    obj = (np.array([x**4,x**3,x**2,x**1,1]) * par).sum()
    grad = (np.array([4*x**3,3*x**2,2*x,1]) * par[:-1]).sum()
    return obj, grad

# Try minimise an example polynomial of 4x^4 + 6x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 5
# with contrainted bound
res = optimize.minimize(
    fun = obj_grad_fun_custom,
    x0 = 0,
    args=(np.array([4,6,3,1,5])), # polynomial coefficients
    jac=True ,
    bounds=[(-2, 10)],
    tol=1e-10)
print(res.x)

# Timing (this takes about 2 ms for me)
%timeit optimize.minimize(fun = obj_grad_fun_custom, x0 = 0, args=(np.array([4,6,3,1,5])), jac=True, bounds=[(-5, 5)], tol=1e-10)
```

Below is what I am planning to do regular with 1 million different order 4 polynomials I would want to minimise locally.  Hopefully, someone could point me to a more suitable package other than `scipy`. Or any alternative methods? Thanks!

```
# Multiple polynomials
result = [] # saving the local minima
poly_sim_no = 1000000 #ideally 1 million or even more
np.random.seed(0)
par_set = np.random.choice(np.arange(10), size=(poly_sim_no, 5), replace=True) #generate some order 4 polynomial coefficients 

for a in par_set:
    res = optimize.minimize(obj_grad_fun_custom, 0,args=(a), jac=True ,bounds=[(-5, 5)], tol=1e-10)
    result.append(res.x)

print(result)
```

Comment: Finding local and extrema of a degree 4 polynomial is the same as finding the roots of a degree 3 polynomial which has closed form solutions (even if with slightly painful formulas) might be faster to just compute them exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're finding the minimum of a polynomial, you can take advantage of the fact that it's easy to take the derivative of a polynomial, and that there are many good algorithms for finding the roots of a polynomial.

Here's how it works:

1. First, take the derivative. All of the points which are minimums will have a derivative of zero.
2. Look for those zeros, aka find the roots of the derivative.
3. Once we have the list of candidates, check that the solutions are real.
4. Check that the solutions are within the bounds you set. (I don't know if you added bounds because you actually want the bounds, or to make it go faster. If it's the latter, feel free to remove this step.)
5. Actually evaluate the candidates with the polynomial and find the smallest one.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

def find_extrema(poly, bounds):
    deriv = poly.deriv()
    extrema = deriv.roots()
    # Filter out complex roots
    extrema = extrema[np.isreal(extrema)]
    # Get real part of root
    extrema = np.real(extrema)
    # Apply bounds check
    lb, ub = bounds
    extrema = extrema[(lb <= extrema) & (extrema <= ub)]
    return extrema

def find_minimum(poly, bounds):
    extrema = find_extrema(poly, bounds)
    # Note: initially I tried taking the 2nd derivative to filter out local maxima.
    # This ended up being slower than just evaluating the function.

    # Either bound could end up being the minimum. Check those too.
    extrema = np.concatenate((extrema, bounds))
    # Check every candidate by evaluating the polynomial at each possible minimum,
    # and picking the minimum.
    value_at_extrema = poly(extrema)
    minimum_index = np.argmin(value_at_extrema)
    return extrema[minimum_index]

# Warning: polynomial expects coeffients in the opposite order that you use.
poly = Polynomial([5,1,3,6,4]) 
print(find_minimum(poly, (-5, 5)))
```

This takes 162 microseconds on my computer, making it about 6x faster than the scipy.optimize solution. (The solution shown in the question takes 1.12 ms on my computer.)

#### Edit: A faster alternative

Here's a faster approach. However, it abandons bounds checking, uses a deprecated API, and is generally harder to read.

```
p = np.poly1d([4,6,3,1,5])  # Note: polynomials are opposite order of before

def find_minimum2(poly):
    roots = np.real(np.roots(poly.deriv()))
    return roots[np.argmin(poly(roots))]

print(find_minimum2(p))
```

This clocks in at 110 microseconds, making it roughly 10x faster than the original.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I think like what you showed the first solution is 6x times quicker than my scipy.optimize solution and your first answer is about 350microseconds on my laptop. 
In terms of the bounds, I do need them instead of trying to speed things up unfortunately so might slow down your solutions a bit

Comment: I do have another on this though. As you might aware I am trying to do this operation on 1m polynomials repeatedly, do you know if there's any vectorisation we could do using numpy (or other packages) for finding the roots or speeding up the whole process? I guess I probably need to explore parallel programming but my workspace only has 2 cores probably won't help a lot.

Comment: @Daves I did find one other idea, which is to use the cubic formula to find the roots rather than the numpy method, which could potentially be faster and easier to vectorize. Here's a link to an implementation: https://github.com/shril/CubicEquationSolver/blob/master/CubicEquationSolver.py But I couldn't wrap my head around the math involved, so I didn't try this.

Comment: ohh that's interesting I think any polynomials with order <=4 can be solved using closed form formulas. Thanks for the link - will dig into it and update you